# Consequences of taking a break from training

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, strength, calories

I'm taking a forced break (about 2-3 weeks) from weightlifting after several months of training. How much are my strength and volume going to drop and at what pace should I start training after coming back? Also is it beneficial to keep protein consumption the same (2g per 1kg) during the break or I should decrease it? Can I use this time to lose some fat and go for calories deficit without losing muscles?

Comment: Seems like you might get part of your answer from http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3475/8039 or http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/2773/8039

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the time threshold for a drop in performance when taking a break from training?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/whats-the-time-threshold-for-a-drop-in-performance-when-taking-a-break-from-tra)

Comment: No changes will happen after a 2 or 3 week break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a couple weeks off won't hurt your strength and could actually be beneficial over the long run as it will give your body some really good rest. I like doing a small deficit when I have to take time off of lifting, you could expect to lose a few lbs over that time. Be aware if you do go on a deficit during your time off you will probably have to drop your weights a little when you come back to lifting. I recommend starting out a little light, like 5-10% lbs lighter than you were doing, and working back up to your old weights over a few workouts.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd talk more about a percentage decline that "10-15lb".